# PdfBox embed fonts into existing document

Tags: java, pdfbox, font-embedding

I have a pdf file which shows font properties in Okular (or whatever PDF viewer) like that:

```
Name: Helvetica 
Type: Type1
File: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation2/LiberationSans-regular.ttf
Embedded: No
```

I want to embed Helvetica with PDFBox 2xx *without* modifying file content (text) itself so it would always available with a file.
Is it possible at all?
I tried something like:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(myFile);

InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/user/fonts_temp/Helvetica.ttf"));
PDFont fontToEmbed = PDType0Font.load(document, stream, true);              
PDResources resources = document.getPage(pageNumber).getResources();
resources.add(fontToEmbed);
//or use the font from pdfbox:
resources.add(PDType1Font.HELVETICA);

document.save(somewhere);
document.close();
```

I also tried to call

```
COSName fontCosName = resources.add(PDType1Font.HELVETICA);
resources.put(fontCosName, font);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

@TilmanHausherr thank you for the clue! But I'm still missing something. Currently my code looks like:

```
PDFont helvetica = PDType0Font.load(document, new FileInputStream(new File("/path/Helvetica.ttf")), false);
...
PDResources resources = page.getResources();
for (COSName fontCosName : resources.getFontNames()){
    if(resources.getFont(fontCosName).getName().equals("Helvetica")) {
        resources.put(fontCosName, helvetica);
    }
}
```

End result shows
`Helvetica CID TrueType Fully Embedded`
But the font is not displayed in PDF file at all now. I mean those places where the font is used are literally empty, blank page... Still something is not there.
Font itself was downloaded from [here](https://freefontsfamily.com/helvetica-font-family/)

Comment: You'd need to know the name that is currently used in the resources, so check these with `resources.getFontNames()`. Also don't subset, so the last parameter should be false.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks a lot. But I have updated post with the next problem - font is not rendered in the document at all

Comment: Please share the PDF before and after

Comment: I see... problem with codes starting at 0 ... try using PDTrueTypeFont instead of PDType0Font. `PDTrueTypeFont.load(document, file, WinAnsiEncoding.INSTANCE);`

Comment: It works! 
But what was the problem? Why PDType0Font didn't fit? 
If I currently call `resources.getFont(<"F1" means Helvetica which is used in an original file>).getSubType()` - it returns `Type0`.  How to understand how to load fonts properly then?

Comment: `System.out.println(doc.getPage(0).getResources().getFont(COSName.getPDFName("F1")).getSubType());` gets me "Type1". With the new file it gets "Type 0". The problem is that this font starts the numbers with 1, while the "old" truetype class starts them with 32 which is also what the standard 14 font did. You can look at the font with PDFDebugger then it's more clear.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks. Now it is more clear. 
But how to distinguish in code, that in document this font is TrueType and that one is Type1? 
My end goal is to embed fonts with a certain logic, where I need to know font type. Because currently `getSubType()` is `Type1` and it is very confusing, as you see I wasn't able to embed Helvetica properly..

Comment: It's complicated... this time it worked nicely. It's possible that it won't work for other files. If your task is to convert files to PDF/A then I'd rather suggest to buy a commercial product. The solution is likely to work only for type 1 non embedded. "how to distinguish in code" well you did, i.e. getSubType, or the class itself.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'm a bit confused now. :) Original file showed `Type1`. While the loading process is done via `PDTrueTypeFond.load()` not via `PDType0Font.load()`. But `getSubType()` returned `Type1`, not `TrueType` - isn't it conflicting logic here?
My task is just to embed fonts and send docs to the printing service. I don't think that PDF/A is what I need

Comment: I tried it. I get "Type1", and after replacement, I get "TrueType". `System.out.println(doc.getPage(0).getResources().getFont(COSName.getPDFName("F1")).getSubType());`

Comment: @TilmanHausherr but shouldn't it normally be "TrueType" before replacement as well? Because Helvetica is a TTF font? Or I am still missing the logic here?

Comment: Helvetica is available both as type1 and truetype. This applies to many fonts. The PDF standard 14 fonts (Times-Roman, Helvetica, Courier, Symbol, Times-Bold, Helvetica-Bold, Courier-Bold, ZapfDingbats, Times-Italic, Helvetica-Oblique, Courier-Oblique, Times-BoldItalic, Helvetica-BoldOblique, Courier-BoldOblique) are all type1, but the same fonts are available as TrueType on many computers (and in PDFs, but then they are not "standard 14" but just some font)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 

You'd need to know the name that is currently used in the resources, so check these with `resources.getFontNames()`

2.
To replace a standard 14 font, use this font object:

```
PDTrueTypeFont.load(document, file, oldFont.getEncoding() /* or WinAnsiEncoding.INSTANCE which is usually right */ );
```

this ensures that the same encoding is used as the standard 14 font. (It's different for the Zapf Dingbats and the Symbol font)

Comment: *"this ensures that the same encoding is used as the standard 14 font"* - Well... no. It does not ensure, it merely makes very probable. Standard 14 fonts can be used with other encodings, too, even custom ones; merely hardly anyone does so. Essentially you need to keep the original encoding to ensure the same encoding..

Comment: I marked that answer as a valid one, but actually there is a great discussion in a comments after the question